# Laravel - Generic Apache 500 error with Envoyer directory structure

Tags: laravel, apache, laravel-5, laravel-envoyer

I am trying to deploy my Laravel 5 site to my VPS using Envoyer. I changed the document root in the site's Apache settings to `/current/public` (settings below), when I do this I receive a generic Apache 500 error. If I use the old `public` directory, everything loads properly.

I also tried `chmod 777 -R storage`, no luck. There are no log entries in the Laravel log, everything deploys fine without errors.

I did notice that if I create a plain HTML document and deploy it via Envoyer, I am able to access it directly with the `/current/public` document root, anything related to Laravel (and only using `current/public`), results in the 500.

Ideas? Would a symlink be a possible solution? Oddly, my Forge configuration on my other Envoyer site has the document root set to `public`, yet there is no symlink to `current/public` that I can see. It may be set to `current/public` and just not displaying that for some reason.

```
customlog:
  -
    format: combined
    target: /usr/local/apache/domlogs/mydomain.org
  -
    format: "\"%{%s}t %I .\\n%{%s}t %O .\""
    target: /usr/local/apache/domlogs/mydomain.org-bytes_log
documentroot: /home/eyf/current/public
group: eyf
hascgi: 1
homedir: /home/eyf
ifmoduleconcurrentphpc: {}

ifmodulemodsuphpc:
  group: eyf
ip: MY.IP.ADDR
owner: root
phpopenbasedirprotect: 1
port: 80
scriptalias:
  -
    path: /home/eyf/public/cgi-bin
    url: /cgi-bin/
  -
    path: /home/eyf/public/cgi-bin/
    url: /cgi-bin/
serveradmin: webmaster@mydomain.org
serveralias: www.mydomain.org
servername: mydomain.org
usecanonicalname: 'Off'
user: eyf
userdirprotect: ''
```

Comment: Did you look at the output of the apache error log?

Comment: Having trouble locating it, to be honest..

Comment: what OS is running on your server?

Comment: Ubuntu, I was able to find this in WHM under Raw Apache Logs for the domain - does not provide any real information: `208.90.136.42 - - [16/Apr/2015:22:58:14 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: That's from the access log. Check `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: I looked for that earlier, I do not have a `/var/log/apache2` or `apache` directory..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75451/discussion-between-drew-hammond-and-nightmicu).

Comment: Just a quick update, I gave Dploy.io a try and had everything setup and working great within a couple of minutes. Auto deploy on commit, runs `git pull origin master`, `composer update`, and `php artisan migrate --force` on deployment. So, basically the same as Envoyer - including the ability to roll back. I want Envoyer to work but I just wasted hours on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I encountered two separate problems here.

The first problem was the fact that I was deploying code as `root` and trying to access a site owned by a cPanel user (`eyf` in this case). Because the files/directories were deployed as `root`, an ownership issue caused the generic 500 error page.

I then tried to connect via Envoyer with `eyf` and there was some sort of SSH key issue - even though I added the key to `eyf` via cPanel, it did not seem to take. Repeated attempts to connect from Envoyer eventually lead the IP address to be blacklisted.

In response to this, Envoyer simply said "Failed" when trying to connect to the server. Immediately after saying "Failed," a warning message would appear saying that there was a problem with PHP-FPM.

Taylor says that this PHP-FPM warning message appears because the connection was unsuccessful and Envoyer could not connect to PHP-FPM. Well, this is totally misleading because I do not have PHP-FPM installed on this server and it has absolutely nothing to do with why the connection failed (it was an SSH authentication problem).

I asked him to **please** improve the warnings/errors for things like this, it stretched what should have been a quick fix into a several hour long tail chasing session. Dploy.io, a competitor, **clearly** showed an SSH connection issue when I first attempted to connect and had forgot the SSH key - "d'oh! Let me fix that," problem solved in less than a minute.

Anyway, back to Envoyer bliss - just a bit ticked. ;) The IP addresses were whitelisted, I added the SSH key manually for the cPanel user (`/.ssh/id_rsa`), and now everything works.